Enterprise architect object creation
I'm using Enterprise architect (Program version - 16.1.1628) . Currently I'm creating sequence diagram in it. I want to create an object by the call from onelifeline. In the given image, message form one object creates another object at that instant. I want such an sequence to be created. How can I do that?
I tried using tutorials of sparx but still not any desired output

This is described in the manual here: https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/17.0/modeling_languages/denotelifecycleofanelement.html
You have to set the lifecycle property of the message to New

After saving that will change your diagram like this:

